# Check if volley Request Response String contains

Tags: java, android-studio

I want to check if the response from volley Request contains "Last Streamed Live on". But no matter what it shows that is doesnt containt it.

```
package com.example.android.Test;

 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.widget.TextView;

 import com.android.volley.Request;
 import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
 import com.android.volley.Response;
 import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
 import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
 import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
```

// private static final int RECOVERY_REQUEST = 1;
   // private YouTubePlayerView youTubeView;

```
TextView button;

public String s;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getWebsite();
}

public void getWebsite() {
    ;
 // Instantiate the RequestQueue.
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    String url = "https://gaming.youtube.com/USERNAME/live";

 // Request a string response from the provided URL.
    button = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.button);
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    button.setText("Response is: " + response);
                        s=response;
                    if (response.contains("Last streamed live on")) {            
//check if String contains "last stream live on" OFFLINE else Stream is LIVE
                        button.setText("OFFLINE");
                    } else {
                        button.setText("Online");
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            button.setText("That didn't work!");
        }
    });
 // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
    queue.add(stringRequest);
   }
}
```

Thank you if you can help me :)

Comment: What is your question?  What does your code do or not do?